# Django and VueJS PWA on Nginx

Tags: django, vue.js, nginx, progressive-web-apps, nginx-reverse-proxy

First of all we build the frontend using npm build. We also configure the assetsDir to /static/ui and outputDir to dist/ui. After the build process is complete, we copy the whole build files to another /static directory, where we load static files through django static. We also specify the /static to alias /etc/var... etc. In

nginx.conf

So everything works fine like this.
The problem arise when I made the VueJS app to pwa, it just won't work, I don't know why, but I have even configured nginx to serve the service-worker.js file. And other files like icons and manifest.json also loads correctly.

Any help on this will be appreciated.

More info: in browser console.log, when we type `'serviceWorker' in navigator` returns true if we are hosting (only the VueJS app) through netlify or vercel, in django's case, it already returns false, thus making it not to support pwa.